# Eager loading of joined properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am looking for a way to eager load some properties of an joined table.

The situation is as following:
I am making an class library which and web service will include.
In this library there must be a method which will return all devices with a specialized set of the device values.

In these device values there is a reference to the option of that value (and some other entities). I am returning a list since i don't want my connection to be open when i give the service the results.

The following problem occurs:

THe web service is trying to get to the option of a device value but get an exception because its not loaded yet and ef tries to lazy load it.
I know i need to eager load these references, but that's where y problem is.

i have the following linq expression:

```
db.Devices.Where(d => (d.Online)).Include("Pictures").Include("Brand").GroupJoin(
            db.DeviceValues.Where(dv => (((((((((((((
             dv.OptionId == new Guid("017AE564-742D-4389-91F8-805A58C77240")) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("4BDD30A6-FBD7-4FFE-A4BA-F25BE2BE4586"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("C6063BA6-231A-424A-92F4-A64BB1BABB7D"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("57BD5C0B-5981-48EB-AE71-A52703FCA0CF"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("A920ED14-8BB4-4097-B3CF-2DE7C79F34DD"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("D29C64EF-69E1-46BB-909B-9B330031A493"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("C3357431-5F4A-40F4-8FDD-1480E2F83D38"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("7CB17F5E-03D3-40E9-A415-3D07BB9A1693"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("D9FCE982-DD66-4FF3-A2A9-5BC84D2BFFF1"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("0E008C9E-A306-E411-AB50-0050569C157F"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("57EF5C9D-CE4D-40D4-93FE-FE3A2A9A4BDA"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("085DE743-A18D-44A6-ACDE-EA5102290F48"))) ||
            (dv.OptionId == new Guid("64A6279A-AB07-41C7-8E6D-3397FBC64FF3")))
            ), d => d.Id, dv => dv.DeviceId, (d, deviceValues) => new DeviceModel
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                DeviceValues = deviceValues.ToList(),
                Brand = d.Brand,
                BrandId = d.BrandId,
                Created = d.Created,
                DeviceCategorie = d.DeviceCategorie,
                Ean = d.Ean,
                DeviceType = d.DeviceType,
                IntroductionDate = d.IntroductionDate,
                Moderator = d.Moderator,
                Modified = d.Modified,
                Name = d.Name,
                Online = d.Online,
                Pictures = d.Pictures,
                SubDeviceFrom = d.SubDeviceFrom,
                SubDeviceFromId = d.SubDeviceFromId,
                dealId = d.dealId,
                display = d.display,
                oldId = d.oldId
            }).ToList();
```

I tried to put my includes before the group join:

```
db.Devices.Where(d => (d.Online)).Include("Pictures").Include("Brand").Include("Option").GroupJoin
```

And:

```
db.Devices.Where(d => (d.Online)).Include("Pictures").Include("Brand").Include("DeviceValues.Option").GroupJoin
```

and i tried to put them after the select

```
new DeviceModel
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                DeviceValues = deviceValues.ToList(),
                Brand = d.Brand,
                BrandId = d.BrandId,
                Created = d.Created,
                DeviceCategorie = d.DeviceCategorie,
                Ean = d.Ean,
                DeviceType = d.DeviceType,
                IntroductionDate = d.IntroductionDate,
                Moderator = d.Moderator,
                Modified = d.Modified,
                Name = d.Name,
                Online = d.Online,
                Pictures = d.Pictures,
                SubDeviceFrom = d.SubDeviceFrom,
                SubDeviceFromId = d.SubDeviceFromId,
                dealId = d.dealId,
                display = d.display,
                oldId = d.oldId
            }).Include("Option")
```

And:

```
new DeviceModel
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                DeviceValues = deviceValues.ToList(),
                Brand = d.Brand,
                BrandId = d.BrandId,
                Created = d.Created,
                DeviceCategorie = d.DeviceCategorie,
                Ean = d.Ean,
                DeviceType = d.DeviceType,
                IntroductionDate = d.IntroductionDate,
                Moderator = d.Moderator,
                Modified = d.Modified,
                Name = d.Name,
                Online = d.Online,
                Pictures = d.Pictures,
                SubDeviceFrom = d.SubDeviceFrom,
                SubDeviceFromId = d.SubDeviceFromId,
                dealId = d.dealId,
                display = d.display,
                oldId = d.oldId
            }).Include("DeviceValues.Option")
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: @downvoter (or anybody else who knows why this got a downvote) I am always eager to learn on how to improve my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force evaluation by calling `toList()` after your `.Include()` calls.

Like this:

```
db.Devices.Where(d => (d.Online)).Include("Pictures").Include("Brand").Include("Option").toList().GroupJoin

db.Devices.Where(d => (d.Online)).Include("Pictures").Include("Brand").Include("DeviceValues.Option").toList().GroupJoin
```

`.Include()` does not enforce evaluation, it only minimizes the number of calls to your database.